# Possible bug in scipy.ndimage.measurements.label?

Tags: python, scipy

I was trying to do a percolation program in python, and I saw a [tutorial](http://dragly.org/2013/03/25/working-with-percolation-clusters-in-python/) recommending scipy.ndimage.measurements.label to identify the clusters. The problem is I stated to notice some odd behaviors in the function. Some elements that should belong to the same cluster are receiving different labels. Here is a code snippet that reproduce my problem.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.ndimage import measurements

grid = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],  #<- notice the last two elements
                 [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

labels, nlabels = measurements.label(grid)

print "Scipy Version: ", scipy.__version__
print
print labels
```

The output I get is:

```
Scipy Version:  0.13.0

[[0 1 1 0 2 2 0 3 0 4]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 5 5 5]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1 0 5 5 5]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 5]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 5]
 [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 5]  #<- The last two elements
 [1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]  #   are set with different labels
 [1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 6]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]]
```

Am I missing something about the way this function is supposed to work or is this a bug?
This is very important because labeling the clusters correctly is crucial to get the right results in percolation.

Thanks, for the help.

Comment: I get what looks like the right answer in 0.14.0.dev-432f16b.  This could be [this bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3025), which seems to have been fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3033).

Comment: if that library is for clustering 2d arrays with relativity to location, then yes it must be a bug ..

Comment: Thanks guys, this seems to be an actual bug. I'm using mahotas for the time being, as was recommended in the link @DSM posted.

Comment: Upgrade to Scipy 0.13.3

Comment: Yup, updating worked too. It's good, because scipy's routine is twice as fast as mahotas'.